# How can I get a sense of slippage before committing to the transaction?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, javascript, price, arbitrage

Of course, as we all know, determining slippage for a certainty is impossible.  I've done my best in my code to reduce my impact on slippage, finding the largest amount across the two pools in my arbitrage that can be withdrawn without exceeding a 1% price impact.

But I'm having trouble finding a resource that I can tap into if I want to get a sense of the pair's slippage over the last X amount of time to decide if I should commit to the transaction or not.

I've tried to pull this information myself, but it's such a massive amount of data, I burn through my Infura API calls in absolutely no time.

I use javascript and npm, so it seems like a lot of the possible resources that WERE there are now gone.

Thoughts on this?